# Windows 10 Pro Ethernet Disconnects from Domain

Tags: windows-10, dns, active-directory, windows-networking, windows-server-2019

ok here is the scenerio:

1. We recently installed Windows 10 Pro on 40+ systems from scratch.
2. Connected them to our Server 2019 Active Directory.

Our IP Lineup:

- Router: 192.168.0.1
- Server: 192.168.0.2
- Subnet: 255.255.254.0
- DNS: 192.168.0.2
- For IPS: 192.168.0.1-192.168.1.255

The Issue:

Randomly our Windows 10 Pro Systems are not communicating with the Active Directory Domain. We lose the mapped network drive and access to roaming profile.
It takes 30 minutes for the station to logon only to find it is using a temp profile.

When the profile is loaded, you try to connect to the mapped drive and it spins. It will connect but loads at a crawl.

I also noticed that the network adapter no longer displayed the domain name.
What is causing this to do this weird issue.

What I did:

1. Disable Network Adapter and Re-Enable (No Go.)
2. Troubleshoot Network Connection Windows. (No Issues).
3. Changed Cables. (Nope).
4. Restarted DNS
5. Restarted System and Servers.

My Temp Solution:
Change the ip address on the system and it works.
Only for the day, then do it again.
So far this is happening to 5 of the 40 PCs.
Everyday, another one seems to be affected.

If anyone has any permanent solution or fix would be great.

Comment: That is strange indeed.  (1) if using Static IP addressing, change to DHCP (IP and DNS) as that is the best way to go.  (2) use the vendor software update app to update BIOS, Chipset and all drivers.  See if either 1 or 2 solve the issue for you.  Check the image you used for errors.

Answer (score 0):

This situation indicates that you may have an IP address conflict. This is common when you use DHCP and static addressing while not making permanent leases. It's just a suggestion. There can be more reasons.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I believe I have found the issue.
Our Server 2019 had a virtual network adapter installed for the Hyper-V remote desktops. I have removed this adapter to default it back to the 10G adapter. So far the issue is closed. Sounds like a connectivity issue with the virtual network adapter.